# android: how to know which process owns a directory?

Tags: android

I have Galaxy S3 and it keeps pop up an advertisement on the bottom of the screen, I want to find out which process is doing this and kill it.

Now I have found the directory that stores all the pictures of the advertisement, but how can I find the process which owns the directory? The directory is: /sdcard/advimg.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to `adb shell` into your phone and then check the owner of that directory with:

```
shell@android:/sdcard $ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 02:08 Alarms
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 02:08 Android
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 02:20 DCIM
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 02:08 Download
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 02:08 Movies
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 02:08 Music
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 04:09 Notifications
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-10-08 15:01 Pictures
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 02:08 Podcasts
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-25 02:22 Ringtones
```

if you see the same output as I do ("sdcard_rw"), then you cannot find the offending app by looking at the directory. try to remember what did you install recently and delete one by one. usually these ads are result of `airpush` embedded in the app, and not very easy to find.